# Need to calculate mean by hour - can't get aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set with time date stamp and and multiple demand location variables, only need to retain 6 of them.  Ultimately, I need to forecast the next 3 hours of demand for all locations.

As a starting point, struggling to use aggregate to get mean performance by hour for all locations.  Using separate as kept getting error with as.POSIXlt and adding format option did not resolve.

```
Citi_Bike_Update <- Citi_Bike %>% 
                separate(time,c("day","hours"),sep=" ", remove = FALSE)
Bike_Update_Hours <- Citi_Bike_Update %>%
                  select("hours","X72", "X79","X82","X83", "X116", 
"X119")
aggregate(.~hours, Bike_Update_Hours,mean)
```

This is producing mean for each location by hour, what I need is mean for all locations by hour

Comment: The "aggregate" tag is a generic tag--what language/ecosystem/whatever are you talking about?

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample data to work with?

Comment: ```Bike_Update_Hours %>% group_by(hours) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean)) ``` can this do the trick?